# Unable to bind simple list array of strings to a ListView

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am currently trying to figure out KendoUI. I am using version 2012.1.322.

I have a simple array of strings `List<string>` returned back to the user in a web method through an AJAX call.

`["name","phone","address","zip"]`

When the ListView binds the list is empty, I only get

`<ul id="fileAlist" data-role="listview" class="k-widget k-listview"></ul>`.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with my template being wrong. What do I have to set instead of `${Object}` to get it to render like:

```
<ul id="fileAlist" data-role="listview" class="k-widget k-listview">
  <li>name</li>
  <li>phone</li>
  <li>address</li>
  <li>zip</li>
</ul>
```

**Here is the current code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#fileAlist").kendoListView({
         template: "<li>${Object}</li>",
         dataSource:
             new kendo.data.DataSource({
                 transport: {
                     read: {
                         url: '@Url.Action("GetColumnNames", new {File="A"})',
                         dataType: "json",
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                     }
                 }
             })
     });
 });
```

**C# Code (in-case you're interested)**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetColumnNames(string file)
    {
        if (file == "A")
        {
            var columns = new List<string>()
                              {
                                  "name",
                                  "phone",
                                  "address",
                                  "zip"
                              };
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = columns, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

**Some other trial and fails**
Here are some of the template ideas I tried and the results that came back. Obviously they all didn't give me the string output I wanted.

- I tried changing the template to be `template: "<li>${}</li>"` and when rendered I get `<li>undefined</li>`
- I tried changing the tempalte to be `template: "<li>$.val()</li>"` and when rendered I get `<li>$.val()</li>`
- I tried changing the tempalte to be `template: "<li>${}.selector</li>"` and when rendered I get `<li>undefined.selector</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several configuration issues in your code. I've simplified the code a bit to concentrate on a working example.

Model class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

View markup, you'll need to play with the list layout to get the desired look:

```
<ul>
    <div id="contactList" style="width: 400px;"></div>
</ul>
```

Note how the template mark up looks like:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <li>${ Name} ${ Phone } ${ Address } ${ Zip }</li>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                        read: {
                          url: "@(Url.Action("GetContacts", "Home"))",
                          dataType: "json",  //switched to json instead of jsonp for this example
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          type: "GET"
                       }
           }
       });

       $("#contactList").kendoListView({
          dataSource: datasource,
          template: kendo.template($("#template").html())  //Link the template to the list view control
       });
   });
```

​

Controller that return json:

```
public ActionResult GetContacts()
{
    List<Contact> list = new List<Contact>();
    Contact contact = new Contact() { ContactId = 0, Name = "Steve", Address = "Some Street", Phone = "1-345-345-3455", Zip = "334566" };
    list.Add(contact);
    contact = new Contact() { ContactId = 1, Name = "Jim", Address = "Another Street", Phone = "1-777-987-3889", Zip = "998754" };
    list.Add(contact);

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

--EDIT--

Here is a controller that'll return a json string without a concrete `Contact` object.

```
public ActionResult GetContacts()
{
    var columns = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>() {
        new Dictionary<string,object>(){ {"Name", "Rex"}, {"Phone", "1-123-123-2342"}, {"Address", "Westwood Drive"}, {"Zip", 928347}},
        new Dictionary<string,object>(){ {"Name", "Smith"}, {"Phone", "1-333-444-5555"}, {"Address", "Allen Way"}, {"Zip", 23456}}
    };

    return Json(columns, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I get your example and I am able to get it to work if I use an object such as Contact in your example `List<Contact> list = new List<Contact>();` What I'm asking for is how to get it to work with a string   `List<string>() list = new List<string>();`

Comment: @lgorrious I've included my controller method that returns the list of strings, in hopes of helping. I did change it to return `json` as well since it should have been that in the first place. I changed it to match an example on the kendo site at one point and forgot to change it back before posting.

Comment: @Mark That does help, take a look at my revised answer. You'll have trouble returning a valid json key+value pair string with just a list of strings. So I've added another dictionary collection to avoid having to have a concrete class.

Comment: #Igorrious, Ahh OK so they are requiring a key + value pair string? And no way to use just a list of strings. That's a bummer

Comment: @Mark Here is a summary of [JSON](http://www.json.org/) formats. Problem with serializing a list of strings is that quotes are added to the whole array element, making it an invalid key+value pair. Currently your controller is returning just an array of strings `["Name","Phone","Address","Zip"]` which are not key+value pair javascript objects that the kendo data source is expecting.

Comment: awesome thank you so much, extremely helpful. I really appreciate the help an explanation it helps